What is the actual purpose of metric_declaration_dedup in amazon-cloudwatch-agent?
In the CloudWatch agent configuration for Prometheus they mention that metric_declaration_dedup enables the "the de-duplication function for the EMF metrics".

metric_declaration_dedup— It set to true, the de-duplication function for the embedded metric format metrics is enabled.

But this deduplication is not explained anywhere else.
What does exactly de-duplicate for embedding metrics format (EMF) do? why there would be duplicate "metric declarations" in the first place?
